# DDR3 DRAM geometry notation

Tags: memory, sdram, dram

When I'm reading the document `2Gb: x4, x8, x16 DDR3 SDRAM`, it states three different types of DDR3 DRAM:

MT41J512M4 – 64 Meg x 4 x 8 Banks

MT41J256M8 – 32 Meg x 8 x 8 Banks

MT41J128M16 – 16 Meg x 16 x 8 Banks

I know the third column 8 means the number of banks for each chip.

But what does the second column (4, 8, or 16) mean here?

It seems that the multiplication of the three columns is 2GB.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: DDR3 is DDR3.....given the same voltage and frequency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking at is referred to [memory geometry notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_geometry#Memory_Geometry_Notation).

For memory chips, the second column is for the memory width. The format you're looking at goes like this: *(Memory Depth per Bank)* x *(Memory Width)* x *(Number of Banks)*

For memory modules, it goes by the same notation, but without the memory width field. So it would look like this *(Memory Depth)* x *(Memory Width)*

Answer (score 1):

You should be reading the document for individual memory chips from [Micron, pdf is here.](https://www.micron.com/~/media/documents/products/data-sheet/dram/ddr3/2gb_ddr3_sdram.pdf) The document has explicit pictures showing block diagrams for each of three different bond-outs. All three chips have 2Gbits capacity (256MBytes).

The first one has data bus width of 4 bits. So it needs 64M * 8 banks  (=512M) of addressing space to get full 2GBits capacity.

The second one has data bus of 8-bits wide and needs 32M * 8 banks (=256M), while the third one has 16-bit-wide data architecture and needs 16M * 8 banks addressing space.

All three chips have sligtly different addreessing schemas, so they could meet different needs of different design areas. And they have slightly different ball-outs. The first two chips are packaged in 78-ball FCGA, while the third one has 96 balls.